# is it possible to set unlimited time for a cookie to a session variable?

Tags: php, session, cookies, session-cookies

How do I set unlimited time to a cookie for a session? I have tried the following below but I still get undefined index notices on my sessions after a day:

```
setcookie('idcourse', 'CourseID', 9999999999);
setcookie('namecourse', 'CourseName', 9999999999);
setcookie('id', 'ID', 9999999999);

if (isset($_POST['idcourse'])) {

$_SESSION['idcourse'] = $_POST['idcourse'];

}

if (isset($_POST['namecourse'])) {

$_SESSION['namecourse'] = $_POST['namecourse'];

}

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

$_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id'];

}
```

Comment: cookies have nothing to do with $_POST. Have you done `session_start()` before you do anything with sessions in ALL the scripts that use the sessions? Note that most cookies suffer from the y2038k problem. You're passing in a 34bit number, and most browsers only use 32bit for time strings.

Comment: You're setting those cookies to expire at 9999999999 which is a unix timestamp for a date in 1986.  What's more, setting those cookies has no bearing on how $_SESSION is handled.

Comment: $_SESSION is related to a single cookie: PHPSESSID.  However, even increasing the lifetime of PHPSESSID won't change how long $_SESSION is stored -- session storage is automatically garbage collected server side.

Comment: @MarcB Yes I do have session_start() in all my scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add an expiry date, or the cookie will act like a session and expire when you leave the website,

what you're doing is nearly right but you need to change it slightly;

You are setting expire 9999999999 (you need to specify a UNIX TIMESTAMP in the future), so i use the following:

```
$inTwoMonths = 60 * 60 * 24 * 60 + time();
setcookie('idcourse', 'CourseID', $inTwoMonths );
setcookie('namecourse', 'CourseName', $inTwoMonths );
setcookie('id', 'ID', $inTwoMonths );
```

will make the cookie expire in 2 months, you can increment this accordingly.

Comment: 9999... is a valid timestamp, it's just that it's >32bits, so probably being ignored/zeroed by most browsers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will mark answer when it allows me to in a couple of mins :)

Comment: I didn't say it wasnt valid, it's 11 / 20 / 86 @ 11:46:39am EST which is no use to anyone, the point is making a timestamp always x* the future of now, not a specific date in history. Glad it helped user!

Answer (score 0):

You should not set cookies to unlimited time. If you need to store something for a longer period, use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html). They don't expire. They're not really cookies but it's also a way of setting information in the browser. You just have to use JavaScript with this.

As for PHP, what you can do is you can rely on databases that will store your information permanently. You can set things in local storage that you can use to load session information. But my suggestion is just use localStorage.